# create flat tar archive: ignoring all parents when adding folders

Tags: tar

I want to add a few folders (recursively) to a new tar archive. All of the folders should be at the root level of the resulting archive. Is there any way to add all folders without their parents, and without `cd`-ing into their directories first and adding them step-by-step?

Consider the following directory structure

```
.
├── bar
│   ├── bar-file
│   └── barsub
│       └── barsub-file
└── foo
    ├── foo-file
    └── foosub
        └── foosub-file
```

I'd like to add *bar* and *foosub* to a tar archive.

```
# add folders with different parents
# could be e.g. /some/foo/foosub and /other/bar as well
$ tar cvf archive.tar bar foo/foosub
a bar
a bar/bar-file
a bar/barsub
a bar/barsub/barsub-file
a foo/foosub
a foo/foosub/foosub-file
```

but what I wanted is

```
.
├── bar
│   ├── bar-file
│   └── barsub
│       └── barsub-file
└── foosub
    └── foosub-file
```

Is there any easy way to create such a *flat* tar archive?

Comment: Your statement, "All folders should be at the root level of the resulting archive" is at odds with your example. Do you mean that you want each _named_ directory to be at the top level of the tarball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU or FreeBSD tar, you can apply a transformation to file names when adding them to an archive (or extracting them).

```
tar czf foo.tgz --transform='!^bar/!!' bar/ foo
```

Portably, you can do the same thing with [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html).

```
pax -w -pe -s'!^bar/!!' foo bar/
```

Answer (score -1):

`tar cvf archive.tar bar -C /path/to/foo/ .`

Comment: there may be some misunderstanding: your code does not add *bar*, but is not what I meant, anyway: I want to add an arbitrary amount of folders to the archive, while their paths do not nessesarily have any shared subpath. So another example would be a new archive with the folders */tmp/foo*, */var/log/bar* and */opt/baz*.